# Incremental MySQL Timestamp conversion for highstock

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the highstock library to show the output data from an magnetometer, but I have a little problem. I store the data in two fields in the bd.
The first value is the datetime where the data was saved, and the second the sensor value:

`2015-06-10 01:29:43 | 15`

but because the sensor send more than one value in one second, I need to convert this time, to a UNIX in a incremental way

let's suppose it's the raw data:

`2015-06-10 01:29:43 | 15
 2015-06-10 01:29:43 | 16
 2015-06-10 01:29:43 | 40
 2015-06-10 01:29:43 | 50
 2015-06-10 01:29:43 | 15
 2015-06-10 01:29:43 | 11`

I convert it to timestamp:

`1444094983 | 15
 1444094983 | 16
 1444094983 | 40
 1444094983 | 50
 1444094983 | 15
 1444094983 | 11`

the last step is convert this time to milliseconds. It's not a problem. The thing is, I need every second that is repeated, have to be an incremental millisecond like this

`1444094983001 | 15
 1444094983002 | 16
 1444094983003 | 40
 1444094983004 | 50
 1444094983005 | 15
 1444094983006 | 11`

but when a new second begins, the incremental number must be restarted and start from 0 again.

I'm working with php and this would be my way to solve it

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($row as $result){
    $row['data_logged'] * 1000 + $i; // assuming I converted it in mysql with UNIX_TIMESTAMP
    if($prev_data != $row['data_logged']) $i = 1;
    $prev_data = $row['data_logged'];
    $i++;
}
```

there is a better/simplest way to do it?

Comment: Do you just want unique data or also the unique way you store this. You can store this easier, and not have this elaborate algorithm...

Comment: the way to store it I don't have problem, it need to be like this: `2015-06-10 01:29:43|15` because I'll not only show it in the highstock library. 
The problem is highstock request a millisecond value, but when I store I do it in datetime way. What do you suggest? even if I have to change the way to store

Comment: No, you do not have to change it, but when it gets to unique storing or data stored as it initially was, there is an easier way to do this. How do you know which record you have to add a ms to, what do you do when you are at the end of a second (999ms)?

Comment: I've a id field to be sure every data is unique. The count never will be 999ms, because the magnetometer only add 15 or 20 records per second (or maximum 30). So my idea is to start from 0 when a new second is read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative design proposal based on the discussion:

There is an auto increment option in MySQL, this option takes care that every inserted record has a unique key. Using that option, the data can be stored without having to have alternate code in php:

```
CREATE TABLE magnoMeterData(
mmdata_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
mmrecordtime TIMESTAMP,
value DOUBLE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4K;
```

Inserting data in this table, leads to a record as follows:

> 1,1444094983001,{your measured value}
>
> 2,1444094983002,{another measured value}
> etc

So the key keeps it unique. The key also has no other function in your data then to keep it unique and run an order by on it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, after trying different things, I couldn't store the timestamp time in milliseconds, I read this option is only available in mysql 5.6.7 or higer.

my problem wasn't to store the data (I already had a unique key). but instead to show it in the highstock graphics, to show more than one data in one second It has to be a milliseconds datetime, but I can only store in timestamp, but timestamp doesn't store millisecond.

My current structure is almost equal to your design. 

I'll keep with the elaborate algorithm until I find something better.

Comment: You can use a long field to store the value: So switch from timestamp type to long type. Then it stores the value you have (and my model then still works too, just as bonus).

Comment: use a long field can be a good option. I'll give a try. Your model works fine,I was working with something like that.